# Import "someObj.proto" was not found or had errors

Tags: java, maven, gradle, protocol-buffers, proto

I need to import a .proto file defined in a jar in our central maven.

Here's my build.gralde:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'http://abc.def.com/content/groups/public/'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://abc.def.com/content/repositories/snapshot/'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'def.abc.someObj:someObj-proto:1.2'
    }
}

protobuf {
    generatedFilesBaseDir="$projectDir/src/"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        // this tells the plugin where your project specific
        // protofiles are located
        proto {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources/proto/'
        }

        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my other.proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.def.abc";

import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "someObj.proto";
```

whenever I try to compile, it's always complaining at

`Import "someObj.proto" was not found or had errors.`

I've downloaded the jar file from this maven, and clearly saw that this someObj.proto is in there.

Any ideas please?

Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used protobuf yet, however, shouldn't these dependencies you specified be moved to script itself instead of being defined in `buildscript` block?